# When and how does a limit at infinity, with a radical, have a negative and positive asymptote? Exmp: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2+7}}{9x+4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> When and how does a limit at infinity, with a radical, have a negative and positive asymptote? Example: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2+7}}{9x+4}$

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2+7}}{9x+4} = \frac{2}{3} , -\frac{2}{3} $

Why is this the case? Our limit is to positive infinity meaning we will never have a negative value to input no?

Furthermore, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2+7}}{9x^2+4} = \frac{2}{3} $   only

What is happening to these cases that I am ignorant of?

Thank you.

Comment: What does “$=\frac23,-\frac23$” mean?

Comment: Perhaps they mean to also include the case where $x \to -\infty$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos both 2/3 and -2/3

Comment: Limits are unique. So, it cannot be both $\frac23$ and $-\frac23$.

Comment: When you pose a question here, it should be in the body of the question, not just the title.  I suspect that is one reason readers focused on the limit you wrote rather than finding the horizontal asymptotes.

Answer (score 1):

If a limit exists, it is unique.  Therefore, it cannot be true that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2 + 7}}{9x + 4} = \frac{2}{3}, -\frac{2}{3}$$

To find the horizontal asymptote(s) of a function $f(x)$, we have to evaluate the limits
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$$
We obtain a horizontal asymptote if at least one of these limits exist.  We get two horizontal asymptotes if these limits both exist and are different.

For the function $f: (-\infty, -4/9) \cup (-4/9, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{36x^2 + 7}}{9x + 4}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2 + 7}}{9x + 4} & = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{|x|\sqrt{36 + \frac{7}{x^2}}}{x\left(9 + \frac{4}{x}\right)} && \text{since $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$}\\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x\sqrt{36 + \frac{7}{x^2}}}{x\left(9 + \frac{4}{x}\right)} && \text{since $|x| = x$ when $x \geq 0$}\\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{36 + \frac{7}{x^2}}}{9 + \frac{4}{x}}\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{36}}{9}\\
& = \frac{6}{9}\\
& = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2 + 7}}{9x + 4} & = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{|x|\sqrt{36 + \frac{7}{x^2}}}{x\left(9 + \frac{4}{x}\right)} && \text{since $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$}\\
& = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-x\sqrt{36 + \frac{7}{x^2}}}{x\left(9 + \frac{4}{x}\right)} && \text{since $|x| = -x$ when $x < 0$}\\
& = \lim_{x \to -\infty} -\frac{\sqrt{36 + \frac{7}{x^2}}}{9 + \frac{4}{x}}\\
& = -\frac{\sqrt{36}}{9}\\
& = -\frac{6}{9}\\
& = -\frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}
Therefore, we get two different horizontal asymptotes since both the limits
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2 + 7}}{9x + 4}$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2 + 7}}{9x + 4}$$
exist and they are different.  They are different because $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ and
$$|x| = \begin{cases}
        x & \text{if $x \geq 0$}\\
        -x & \text{if $x < 0$}
        \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If your exercise book states that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{36x^2+7}}{9x+4}=\frac{2}{3},-\frac{2}{3}
$$
then trash it: it won't do you any good.

You are correctly observing that over $(0,\infty)$ the function is positive, so the limit for $x\to\infty$, if it exists, can only be nonnegative (if finite) or $\infty$.

On the contrary, over $(-\infty,-1)$ the function is negative, so the limit for $x\to-\infty$, if it exists, can only be nonpositive (if finite) or $-\infty$.

Both limits exist and are finite. For $x\to\infty$, perform the substitution $x=1/t$ over $(0,\infty)$; the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\dfrac{36+7t^2}{t^2}}}{\dfrac{9+4t}{t}}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{36+7t^2}}{9+4t}=\frac{6}{9}=\frac{2}{3}
$$
We can pull $t^2$ outside the square root in the numerator because we're assuming $t>0$.

For $x\to-\infty$, perform the substitution $x=-1/t$ over $(-\infty,-1)$; the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{\dfrac{36+7t^2}{t^2}}}{\dfrac{-9+4t}{t}}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{36+7t^2}}{-9+4t}=-\frac{6}{9}=-\frac{2}{3}
$$
Again, we're assuming $t>0$, so we can pull $t^2$ outside the square root.

Comment: But some people use $\infty$ to mean either $-\infty$ or $+\infty$. It is possible that the exercise wanted to consider two separate cases -case 1): $\infty$ means $+\infty$ and case 2): $\infty$ means $-\infty$.

Comment: @Koro That's true, but such notation is unfortunate, misleading and abusive.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The limit is $\frac23$. There is also a negative limit:
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{36x^2+7}}{9x+4} =  -\frac{2}{3}.$$